# Google App Engine: webapp2 routing not working

Tags: python, routes, webapp2

I created these routes:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainPage),
  ('/empresa', Empresa),
  ('/empresa/perfil', EmpresaPerfil),
], debug=True)
```

With these handlers:

```
class Empresa(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    template_values = {}
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('templates/empresa/index.html')
    self.response.write(template.render(template_values))

class EmpresaPerfil(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    template_values = {}
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('templates/empresa/perfil.html')
    self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

But every time I call "empresa/perfil" it returns a 404.

I thought it was trying to reach a method with a parameter named "perfil", but after modifying the response handler I still get the same error.

Am I missing something?

Edit: including app.yaml

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /img
  static_dir: templates/img/
- url: /empresa
  static_dir: templates/empresa/
- url: /estudiante
  static_dir: templates/estudiante/
- url: /css
  static_dir: templates/lib/css/
- url: /js
  static_dir: templates/lib/js/
- url: /templates
  static_dir: templates/
- url: /.*
  script: guestbook.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2                                                                  
  version: latest
```

Comment: how does your app.yaml look like?

Comment: there, I just added it.

Comment: are those two classes: `Empresa` and `EmpresaPerfil` in the `guestbook.py` file? that's the entry point of your project defined in the app.yaml

Comment: yes, they're all in guestbook.py.

Comment: Oh, I missed it completely, the `- url: /empresa` rule in your app.yaml takes precedence over the handler `EmpresaPerfil`, if you have no `perfil` under the `templates/empresa/` folder it will return a 404

Comment: So should I add "perfil" as a separate rule? I thought I only needed the rule to point at the directory where all my html files were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the app.yaml wasn't catching that route. 
I modified the following line to fix that:

```
- url: /empresa/.*
  static_dir: templates/empresa/
```

Thanks to [Rafael Barros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/629187/rafael-barros) for his help :)